# Web Compiler converting CoffeeScript to JavaScript with require()

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, web-essentials, iced-coffeescript, web-compiler

I'm using Web Compiler for Visual Studio 2015, and I'm trying to compile a coffeescript file into a normal javascript file, but whenever I compile the coffeescript.js file I get the javascript.js, but with:

```
// Generated by IcedCoffeeScript 108.0.11
(function() {
var iced;

iced = require('iced-runtime');
...
```

appended to the beginning. We don't use Node.js, so the `require()` fails and hence my AngularJS controller is unrecognized.

Is there a setting within Web Compiler that disables the insertion of the above? I just want the coffeescript compiled into normal JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Compiler seems to be using the IcedCoffeeScript compiler, with the [`--runtime`](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/#usage) flag [defaulting to `node`](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/blob/030ef6a1a7d4ad51cdf21c97525c2f7fdc82eb94/src/WebCompiler/Compile/IcedCoffeeScriptOptions.cs#L50), causing the `require` you see.

You should have a `compilerconfig.json` at the project root. Try setting an explicit option for the `runtime`:

```
compilers: {
  coffeescript: {
    runtimeMode: 'inline' // or 'window' or even 'none'
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but as an FYI for others. Web Compiler defaults to use the icedcoffeescript compiler which introduces [flaws](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/202) in some situations. I have since excluded it from my project.